# Can I combine two functions logic into one so it can be reused - SOLID Dry C#

Tags: c#

I want to combine two functions in another one that I will reuse in order to follow the SOLID principles for dry code. I have two different lists which both include ids as properties of its objects. I want to combine this logic and give to another method parameters , so that it will execute the logic that is duplicated.

```
public static bool IsParfumesStyleValid(string style, List<Parfumes> parfumes)
{
    foreach (var parfume in parfumes)
    {
        var matchNumbersInDecimal = Regex.IsMatch(parfume.Id, "^(\\d*\\.)\\d+");
        var matchFullNumbers = Regex.IsMatch(parfume.Id, "^\\d+$");
        var matchNumbersWithHalfs = Regex.IsMatch(parfume.Id, "^[1-9][0-9]*\\/[1-9][0-9]*");

        if ((style == "decimal" && !matchNumbersInDecimal)
            || (style == "full" && !matchFullNumbers)
            || (style == "numbersWithHalfs" && !matchNumbersWithHalfs))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}


public static bool IsCosmeticsStyleValid(string style, List<Cosmetics> cosmetics)
{
    foreach (var item in cosmetics)
    {
        var matchNumbersInDecimal = Regex.IsMatch(item.Id, "^(\\d*\\.)\\d+");
        var matchFullNumbers = Regex.IsMatch(item.Id, "^\\d+$");
        var matchNumbersWithHalfs = Regex.IsMatch(item.Id, "^[1-9][0-9]*\\/[1-9][0-9]*");

        if ((style == "decimal" && !matchNumbersInDecimal)
            || (style == "full" && !matchFullNumbers)
            || (style == "numbersWithHalfs" && !matchNumbersWithHalfs))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

My suggestion is not working now and it looks like this.

```
public static bool IsObjectsStyleValid(string style, List<Cosmetics> cosmetics,List<Parfumes> parfumes)
{
    var list; 
    if (parfumes == null)
    {
        list = cosmetics;
    }
    else
    {
        list = parfumes;
    }

    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        var matchNumbersInDecimal = Regex.IsMatch(item.Id, "^(\\d*\\.)\\d+");
        var matchFullNumbers = Regex.IsMatch(item.Id, "^\\d+$");
        var matchNumbersWithHalfs = Regex.IsMatch(item.Id, "^[1-9][0-9]*\\/[1-9][0-9]*");

        if ((style == "decimal" && !matchNumbersInDecimal)
            || (style == "full" && !matchFullNumbers)
            || (style == "numbersWithHalfs" && !matchNumbersWithHalfs))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

May someone give me proper example for my case?

Comment: I suggest to use the generics with the T type for these particular two methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can control the `Cosmetics` and `Parfumes` classes, I would have them both implement an interface with a public string Id property:

```
interface IHaveId
{
    string Id {get;}
}
```

Then you can do something like this, with almost no change to the code you've posted:

```
public static bool IsStyleValid<T>(string style, List<T> product)
where T : IHaveId
{
    foreach (var item in product)
    {
        var matchNumbersInDecimal = Regex.IsMatch(item.Id, "^(\\d*\\.)\\d+");
        var matchFullNumbers = Regex.IsMatch(item.Id, "^\\d+$");
        var matchNumbersWithHalfs = Regex.IsMatch(item.Id, "^[1-9][0-9]*\\/[1-9][0-9]*");

        if ((style == "decimal" && !matchNumbersInDecimal)
            || (style == "full" && !matchFullNumbers)
            || (style == "numbersWithHalfs" && !matchNumbersWithHalfs))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can combine them if you use a selector func to point out which property to use for "Id".

```
public static bool IsObjectsStyleValid<T>(string style, IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, string> idSelector)
{
    foreach (var id in items.Select(idSelector))
    {
        if ((style == "decimal" && !Regex.IsMatch(id, "^(\\d*\\.)\\d+"))
            || (style == "full" && !Regex.IsMatch(id, "^\\d+$"))
            || (style == "numbersWithHalfs" && !Regex.IsMatch(id, "^[1-9][0-9]*\\/[1-9][0-9]*")))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Usage:

```
IsObjectsStyleValid("decimal", parfumes, x => x.Id);
IsObjectsStyleValid("decimal", cosmetics, x => x.Id);
```

Comment: This is a great solution if the target classes either can't be changed or unknown in advance. However, it makes the calling code slightly more cumbersome - and so the generic approach is slightly better IMHO. +1 though for giving this option.

Answer (score 0):

**Using extension method with applying method constraint you can achieve it,  please check below example**

```
interface IProduct
{
    string Id {get;}
}
class Cosmetic : IProduct
{
 public string Id {get;}
//Other members
}
class Parfume : IProduct
{
 public string Id {get;}
//Other members
}

    public static class AppExtension
    {
        public static bool IsStyleValid<T>(this List<T> instance, string style)
  where T : IProduct
        {
            foreach (var item in instance)
            {
                var matchNumbersInDecimal = Regex.IsMatch(item.Id, "^(\\d*\\.)\\d+");
                var matchFullNumbers = Regex.IsMatch(item.Id, "^\\d+$");
                var matchNumbersWithHalfs = Regex.IsMatch(item.Id, "^[1-9][0-9]*\\/[1-9][0-9]*");

                if ((style == "decimal" && !matchNumbersInDecimal)
                    || (style == "full" && !matchFullNumbers)
                    || (style == "numbersWithHalfs" && !matchNumbersWithHalfs))
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
    }


static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Cosmetics> cosmetics = GetData();

    bool x = cosmetics.IsStyleValid("decimal");
}
```